# Product calculation in java using BigDecimal

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to do a Product calculation in Java, but I can't seem to get it to work. I tried using WolframAlpha initially, but I exceeded processing time.

The formula is: `Product (n/1220096908800), n=1..1220096908800`

This is the code I've tried:

```
BigDecimal z = new BigDecimal("0");
BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal("1220096908800");

for (BigDecimal x = BigDecimal.valueOf(1); x.compareTo(n) < 0; x = x.add(BigDecimal.ONE)) {
    z = (x.divide(n)).multiply(z);
}

z = z.setScale(8, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);

df.setMinimumFractionDigits(6);

df.setGroupingUsed(false);
System.out.print(df.format(z));
```

Thoughts?

EDIT: This is the error I'm receiving

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.
    at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:1690)
    at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:34)
```

Comment: What does "can't seem to get it to work" mean?

Comment: So you're doing this loop where you divide 2 numbers, then multiply by 0, which is going to be 0 every time. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: when you say product(n/12000..) what that does that mean, product of what?

Comment: ControlAltDel
you're right about that error, z should be "1"
I'm trying to achieve this -> Product (n/1220096908800), n=1..1220096908800

Eduardo Dennis
I'm trying to do a Product calculation, similar to Summation, but with multiplication instead of division

Answer (score 1):

You are starting with `BigDecimal z = new BigDecimal("0");`
So if you multiplying everything by 0, it will always come back to 0.

Another issue is that you are trying to divide at some point two `BigDecimal` that can't be divided.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

> if the exact quotient cannot be represented (because it has a
>   non-terminating decimal expansion) an ArithmeticException is thrown.

If I am understand correctly you are trying to compute is:

```
1220096908800!/1220096908800^1220096908800
```

Maybe you should have a look at [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation):

or how this lecture: [How Does n! Compare to n^n](https://www.coursera.org/learn/advanced-calculus/lecture/Ok4zN/how-does-n-compare-to-n-n)

Comment: that's not the same as doing a product (Π) calculation, it's similar to summation, the calculation you linked isn't equivalent or comparable, hence the Stirling's approximation wouldn't apply, you are right about setting z to 0 though, it should be starting as 1

Comment: let;' take N = 1220096908800

Product (n/N) = 1/N * 2 / N * (...) * N/N
= (1 * 2 * ... N) / (N * N * ... * N)


and (1 * 2 * ... * N ) = N !


and `N * N * ... N` N times = `N power N` =  `N ^ N`

so Product (n/1220096908800)  = 1220096908800! / (1220096908800  ^ 1220096908800)